# Sending image as base64string to WebAPI; base64 string is too long

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, azure-sql-database, httpclient, restful-authentication

I recently followed these tutorials by Ahsan Siddique

Developing RESTful API in ASP.Net With Azure Database.

Part 1
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-sql-database-in-azure-portal/

part 2
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/developing-restful-api-in-asp-net-with-add-method/

Part 3
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/developing-restful-apis-in-asp-net-with-retrieve-update-and-delete-functions/

Consuming RESTful API in Xamarin.Android

part 4
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-restful-apis-in-xamarin-android/

I managed to get all the codes to work but I got stuck at the part where i'm trying to pass the base64 string to the web api. The tutorial didn't have the portion that I got stuck at. I tested my POST API on Postman and I get this error message, "HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long."

Below you can see a portion of my codes:

```
public String BitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    //Java.IO.ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new Java.IO.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, memStream);
    byte[] byteArray = memStream.ToArray();
    return Base64.EncodeToString(byteArray, Base64Flags.Default);
}

User user = new User ();
user.ID = "1";
user.name = "Kelly";
user.profilepic = BitmapToBase64(NGetBitmap(uri)); //this is the part where base64string is too long

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string url = $"http://test.azurewebsites.net/api/User/{user.ID}?name={user.name}&profilepic={user.profilepic}";
var uri1 = new System.Uri(url); //base64
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(feedback);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
response = await client.PostAsync(uri1, content);

if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Your profile is updated.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
else
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Your profile is not updated." + feedback.profilepic, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

I need help! Thank you in advance!

Update:
This is how my controller class currently look like

```
public HttpResponseMessage Update_User(int ID, string name, string profilepic)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }

    UserTable newUser = new UserTable();
    var entry = db.Entry<UserTable>(newUser);
    entry.Entity.ID = ID;
    entry.Entity.name = name;
    entry.Entity.profilepic = profilepic;
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "Your profile is updated.");
}
```

Comment: Why are you including the image in the URL rather than in the body of the POST?

Comment: The base64 encoded image should not be part of the query string/URL. Please add it to the body using a post request

Comment: As already replied by other users: you should use the POST method here. Not only to overcome the problem that the data is too big to fit in a URI, but also to use the HTTP protocol as intended: GET is for read actions, POST (and other methods like PUT and DELETE) are for update actions. You may want to have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, don't send the base64 image as part of the url/GET param.

Instead attach it to the body of the POST request.

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("profilepic", user.profilepic)
});
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast reply but as I am still a newbie. I am wondering how my controller class should look like after I have added your codes. I have included the codes above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are after. Does the suggested change work? If this is a separate question to the original, please mark as accepted and open a new question relating to the issue.

Comment: I am trying to store base64string in Azure SQL database. I am currently developing a Xamarin Android app.

Comment: then please open a new question related to the issue you are experiencing. If this has solved the issue outlined in the original post, please mark as accepted